# Is there any jquery menu plugin like this one ?

Tags: jquery, css, menu

http://www.beltal.com/

[image]

Thanks for any information!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can find exactly like the one you've shown, you could check [this](http://www.designchemical.com/lab/jquery-vertical-mega-menu-plugin/examples/) which you can customize to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a plugin for that. You could easily write your own.

Put the id of the div you want to display as the value of a `data-` attribute on each menu item. Then on hover of each menu item display the appropriate div.